# How do you find the number of rectangles in a 2D matrix of 0s and 1s?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have searched a number of posts here on SO as well as other resources online. Most of them provide a solution for finding the maximum area of a rectangle in a 2D matrix, which I understand. However, I am curious to know the way you find the number of rectangles in a 2D matrix where a rectangle is **represented by 1s**.

**Update:**
Apologize for not clarifying the scenario as to what classifies as a rectangle - it is considered a rectangle if the cells inside a certain perimeter are **filled** with 1s.

Comment: For a rectabgle to count, do just the corners need to be 1, or the sides, or does the rectangle have to be filled with 1s?

Comment: @OleV.V., I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non-optimized version that should give the correct result:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < m; col++) {
        // count all rectangles with top left corner at (row,col)
        int upperLimit = m; // this number sets the max width that rectangles with greater
                            // height can have (depends on the 1s in the rows above)
        for (int r = row; r < n && matrix[r][col] == 1; r++) {
            int c = col;
            for (; c < upperLimit && matrix[r][c] == 1; c++)
                sum++;
            upperLimit = c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I admit there’s always a balance to find when considering whether to write code for an asker. Generally we say we don’t, mostly because we don’t want to attract “gimme the codez” kinds of questions. I think this is one of the cases we one can safely refrain and can give an explanation-only answer instead. I liked the pseudocode answer better than this one.

Comment: No in my opinion 10 is the correct answer, I don't know how you get 8. If we go from left to right and top down it is 4 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 1 = 10. Also I think the formulation of the pseudo code is very vague and much more complicated than it has to be. @OleV.V.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how my counting was incorrect. One reason I made an error was your code is a bit tricky and would have deserved better explanation than what you gave.

Answer (score 2):

Some pseudo-code:

```
for x_0 in rows:
    for x_1 > x_0 in rows:     # symmetry-reduction: x_0 always "top"
        for y_0 in columns:
            for y_1 > y_0 in columns:  # symmetry reduction: y_0 always "left"
                if mat[x_0, y_0] == mat[x_0, y_1] == mat[x_1, y_0] == mat[x_1, y_1] == 1:
                    found rectangle!
```

Keep in mind: it's pseudo-code (partially based on python-style) and the boolean-evaluation does not work like that in most languages!

The symmetry-reduction is not only improving performance, but it's also important when you are counting. There are visually equal rectangles, where x_0 and x_1 just take different roles (left and right point). You have to decide how to count this.

**Edit:** After Ole V.V.'s comment above i realized that there are indeed very different interpretation's. Most of these can be realized with the pseudo-code above but with a different check on the inner-level. But that might be your work then (and there are more-tuned approaches possible then in some cases)!

Here i assume, a rectangle is just defined by 1's at the 4 corners!

**Edit:** After your new definition of a rectangle, the inner-check changes to:

```
if all(mat[x_0:x_1, y_0:y_1])  # python/numpy inspired pseudo-code!
```

So basically you might check all the values defined by the 4 border-points. That's easy and solves your problem.

But of course you could be much more efficient. It might be wise to add some binary-flag which indicates if the current rectangle (they are growing) is still filled with only 1's. Actually you would probably need 2 binary-flags, 1 for each dimension. Then you can do early-stopping if that's not the case.

Comment: @sashcha,  thanks for the answer. Please check my updated question. I have clarified details as to what classifies as a rectangle.